# Multiple instances of Snap.svg causes corruption

Tags: javascript, html, svg, snap.svg

I wish to display several SVG's on a single web page, each within a separate DOM element, which I am loading and then manipulating with Snap.svg (v0.5.1). The SVG's are created in Illustrator.

A single svg on the page loads and animates as expected. However when attempting to load multiple, small corruptions appear in at least one of the SVG's. I suspect I am using Snap incorrectly, but cannot find examples of loading it into separate DOM elements on the same page.

```
   var s=Snap(".dom-element");
   Snap.load("my-pic1.svg", onSVGLoaded );
   function onSVGLoaded( data ){ 
      s.append( data );
      //do something
   }

   var s2=Snap(".dom-element2");
   Snap.load("my-pic2.svg", onSVGLoaded2 );
   function onSVGLoaded2( data ){ 
       s2.append( data );
       //do something
    }

    var s3=Snap(".dom-element3");
    Snap.load("my-pic3.svg", onSVGLoaded3 );
    function onSVGLoaded3( data ){ 
        s3.append( data );
        //do something
    }
```

Is there another way of loading multiple svg's into individal elements without calling a new instance of Snap each time (if that is the issue here)?

Comment: Do the SVG files have id values which are duplicates? All ids must be unique. If you're loading all 3 SVGs into the same document then there can't be duplicates even across those files.

Comment: Your comment solved my issue. Whilst it was not id's, the classes were all named the same by Illustrator for each SVG, so were conflicting. Illustrator needs a way of adding a suffix to the classes as you export the SVG. Thank you for your help.